# How do I Include Google Adsense script in my existing random banner script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I am currently using my own script to manage banners/ads on my site. I have an array which contains basic html with a link and an image, then som script that pulls one item from the array at random and displays it.

I would like to add Google Adsense as one of the items in the array, but just can't get it working. I *think* what I need to do is include just a call to the Google script in the array, but am a little lost. Can anyone offer any help or advice?

My array is setup like this:

```
var headerSpons = ['<iframe src=\"url\" width=\"728\" height=\"90\" scrolling=\"no\" border=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" style=\"border:none;\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>']
```

The Adsense Code I need to include looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxx";
/* Header Banner */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```